# Audio amplifier schematic explanation

Tags: transistors, amplifier, basic, repair

I'm repairing an old amplifier Sansui A-40 which I got from a friend. Here's a portion of the original schematic:

[image: Channel 2 - Sansui A40]

What does the red marked area do, and how does it work?  I'm not familiar with that circuit, and I won't dive in for a repair unless I understand the whole circuit.

From what I understand, the left portion of TR06 as an emitter-follower used as an input buffer for the preamp and amp stages. What does the right side of TR06 do?

**(In this case the failing in the equipment isn't important, I want to learn the inner workings)**

Just in case you need it, the double PNP transistor is a 2SA798.
(The full schematic is everywhere on the web, just look for sansui A40 schematic and there you have it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a standard differential pair. The left transistor takes a signal from a previous stage and the right transistor takes a fraction of the output signal and creates negative feedback to control the gain of the amplifier.

Here's an example that uses NPN transistors as the differential pair: -

[image]

Your circuit is made slightly more complicated because of the Baxandall tone control circuit sat right on the right transistor's base which, is essentially doing this: -

[image]

Comment: thank you, now that you explained it i feel foolish for not figuring it out myself.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit given in your question is a power amplifier and actually has no significant difference from an opamp.

The marked area is a differential amplifier (the two bases are inputs) and has the same job as Vin- and Vin+ pair in an opamp.